# Rails 3 + html_safe, raw

Tags: ruby-on-rails

html_safe and raw works good inside Viwe, but it dosent work inside action inside controller

```
a = "<p> sample text </p>"
```

> **Inside view** <%=a.html_safe%>
>   give output  "Sample text"

**Inside controller**

```
def test 

   a = "<p> sample text </p>" 
   a.html_safe 

end

this returns the as it is "<p> sample text </p>"
```

please guide me how to make this html_safe work inside controller action....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should simply do:

```
def test 
  @a = "<p> sample text </p>".html_safe 
end
```

---

Just tried myself, and it works properly. In my view I have

```
<%= @a %>
```

Comment: it returns "<p> sample text </p>"

Comment: in works inside view... but when you inspect @a inside the controller it prints "<p> sample text </p>"

Comment: actually iam using prawn gem to generate pdf, i am generating pdf from inside controller method, when i try to append a verialble with html_safe it dosent work

Comment: Mmm ok, I understand better. Anyway, why don't you create a dedicated view for your pdf? it will be much easier to maintain as it would stick to mvc pattern

Comment: i have view for pdf; that works,  but inside pdf file values are displayed with html tags

Comment: ok, so last chance: do you make manipulation with your strings? Indeed `"#{@a}, #{@b}"` would not be html safe because `@b` isn't.

Comment: I dont do any manipulation, i fetch value directly from database, it comes as string with html tags, and assign it to a @variable. After this i append this variable to pdf.table

Comment: Try to look this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722925/rails-3-prawn-pdf-html-safe)