# rails 3 + prawn pdf + html_safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using prawn gem to generate PDF reports,

```
@user.description returns as string "<b>sample text</b> &nspb; <p>sample text</p>"
```

while appending values to the pdf table

```
pdftable = Prawn::Document.new
pdftable.table([["#{@user.description}"]],
         :column_widths => {0 => 50, 1 => 60, 2 => 280, }, :row_colors => ["ffffff"])
```

in this case generated pdf has content with html tags, even i tried applying html_safe but it is not escaping tags.

is it possible to use/apply html_safe inside prawn pdftable, in order to escape html tags?

Comment: What is showing up in the PDF, exactly, and what do you want to show up instead?

Comment: in pdf its showing up "<b>sample text</b> &nspb; <p>sample text</p>" , instead it should be only text i.e "Sample text sample text", html_safe should be applied

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what `html_safe` does--it simply tells Rails that the string should not be escaped when used in a view. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414267/strip-html-from-string-ruby-on-rails) for a solution.

Comment: how one can make htMl_safe work in controller, or is there any alternate method for this.

Comment: Did you try all the same, but without quotation marks? `pdftable.table([[@user.description.html_safe]] ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once again, `html_safe` is not the method you should be using; it doesn't do what you think it does. All `html_safe` does is mark the string as safe, thus telling Rails that it does not need to escape it in a view. When using Prawn it would have no effect.

What it sounds like you want to do is not *escape* HTML, but *strip* HTML tags from the string. Rails has an HTML sanitizer in `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper`, but by default it allows certain tags; you can turn this behavior off using the `tags` attribute.

```
class MyClass
  include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

  def remove_html(string)
    sanitize(string, :tags => {}) # empty tags hash tells it to allow no tags
  end
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.remove_html "<b>sample text</b> &nspb; <p>sample text</p>"
 => "sample text &nspb; sample text"
```

You can `include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` in your controller to get access to the `sanitize` method.

Note that the `&nbsp;` is still in the string; if you want to remove these HTML entities, you'll need to use some other method; the [HTMLEntities gem](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) is one such method:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'htmlentities'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> coder = HTMLEntities.new
=> #<HTMLEntities:0x007fb1c126a910 @flavor="xhtml1">
[3] pry(main)> string = "sample text &nbsp; sample text"
=> "sample text &nbsp; sample text"
[4] pry(main)> coder.decode string
=> "sample text   sample text"
```

(note that in your example, the text says `&nspb;` instead of `&nbsp;`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me to little extent, but still some of the tags generated from one of the HTML editor Tinymce, are not being converted to actual text with htmlentities.   But it works really good when i use raw or htnm_safe in the View.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a way to use prawn's inline format than you could also do as following:

```
pdftable = Prawn::Document.new
cell = make_cell(content: "#{@user.description}", inline_format: true)
pdftable.table([[cell]])
```

Comment: i used this answer but i was rendering in a view and therefore had to use `pdf.make_cell(...)`